# I want to make a new column based on pandas dataframe rows having equal values in multiple columns and different values in 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have 4 columns in a pandas dataframe and millions of rows. I need to compare all the rows and make a new column 'value' such that any rows should have the same values in columns 'ID', 'Amount' and 'date' and different values in column 'debit/credit' ( 'debit/credit' takes only debit, credit as values)
for eg. the following table

| ID | Amount | date | debit/credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 11JAN2021 | debit |
| 256 | 20 | 03FEB2021 | credit |
| 123 | 10 | 11JAN2021 | credit |
| 256 | 30 | 22FEB2021 | debit |
| 568 | 40 | 03MAR2021 | credit |
| 568 | 40 | 15MAR2021 | debit |

should give me something like this

| ID | Amount | date | debit/credit | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 11JAN2021 | debit | 1 |
| 256 | 20 | 03FEB2021 | credit | 0 |
| 123 | 10 | 11JAN2021 | credit | 1 |
| 256 | 30 | 22FEB2021 | debit | 0 |
| 568 | 40 | 03MAR2021 | credit | 0 |
| 568 | 40 | 15MAR2021 | debit | 0 |

Comment: What is the logic for the "value" column? "different values" is not clear enough

Comment: 'Value' is '1' if all columns are same but debit/credit is different and '0' otherwise

Comment: Please stop reversing the edits.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['value'] = (df.groupby(['ID', 'Amount', 'date'])['debit/credit']
                 .transform('nunique').eq(2).astype(int)
               )
```

output:

```
    ID  Amount       date debit/credit  value
0  123      10  11JAN2021        debit      1
1  256      20  03FEB2021       credit      0
2  123      10  11JAN2021       credit      1
3  256      30  22FEB2021        debit      0
4  568      40  03MAR2021       credit      0
5  568      40  15MAR2021        debit      0
```

Alternative using `pivot_table` and `merge`:

```
cols = ['ID', 'Amount', 'date']
s = (df.assign(x=True)
       .pivot_table(index=cols, columns='debit/credit',
                    aggfunc=any, fill_value=False)
       .all(1).astype(int)
    )
out = df.merge(s.rename('value'), left_on=cols, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Comment: Ahh I was stuck in trying to get the index of all True and False values and forgot I can just convert them into `int`.